# Docker Postgres psql connection: FATAL: role "..." does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, express, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to build a node express & Postgres application.

**Problem**
I cannot enter the container with psql to inspect the tables but my initial migration is logging that there was a successful migration.

--- EDIT ---
[Codebase](https://github.com/MrT3313/ReactQuery_Demo)
--- END EDIT ---

**Running Containers**

note: the db is immediately shutting down and this might be the reason my psql is failing while the migration (which is creating a new connection) is working??

```
## -- LOG FROM RUNNING DB CONTAINER -- ##

2021-12-04 22:08:27.683 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

2021-12-04 22:08:27.683 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

2021-12-04 22:08:27.688 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

2021-12-04 22:08:27.723 UTC [76] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-12-04 22:08:27 UTC

2021-12-04 22:08:27.734 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

[image]

**✅ Successful Migration Command**
`docker exec reactquery_demo-backend-1 npm run migrate`

**❌ Failed psql Command(s)**

1. trying to connect to db w/ docker user: `psql -p 5432 -d reactquery_demo_db -U docker`
2. trying to connect to db container w/ docker user:`psql -p 5432 -d reactquery_demo-db-1 -U docker`

THE ERROR:
`psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "docker" does not exist`

- I have seen posts about this being caused by the fact that a POSTGRES_USER is not added in the docker-compose but I have that in mine (as shown below)
- I have also tried:

  - uninstalling / reinstalling / upgrading postgresql w/ homebrew
  - running `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` and then restarting Postgres w/ homebrew
  - stopping the homebrew Postgres processes completely so that is does not conflict with docker Postgres??

    - when I do this I get the following error: `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`

---

**Repo Structure**

[image]

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ReactQueryDemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Simple Overview of React Query for Weekly Dev Meeting",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.js",
    "dev:watch": "nodemon index.js",
    "migrate": "node db/scripts/migrate.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "knex": "^0.95.14",
    "pg": "^8.7.1"
  }
}
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend: 
    build: ./backend
    ports: 
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    ports: 
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=react_query_demo_db
    volumes: 
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:17

WORKDIR /backend

# copy everything from local backend dir
# into your current working directory in
# the container: /backend
COPY . .

# install dependencies in the container
# the .dockerignore does not copy the 
# node_modules || Dockerfile itself
RUN npm i

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**Backend Index**

```
// server
const server = require("./api/server.js");

// port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// listening
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`*** \n\tServer listening on http://0.0.0.0:${PORT}\n***`)
});
```

**Server**

```
// import packages
const express = require('express')

// import routes

// create server
const server = express()
// configure server
server.use(express.json())

// configure routing

// base route
server.get('/', async(req,res) => {
  console.log('React Query Demo Server Running')
  res.json({ status: "SUCCESS", message: "React Query Demo Server Running" })
})

// exports
module.exports = server
```

**Database Index**

```
// imports
const knex = require('knex')

module.exports = knex({
  client: 'postgres',
  connection: {
    host: 'db',             // this is the name of the service in the docker-compose
    user: 'docker',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'react_query_demo_db'     
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you try `docker exec react_query_demo_db-1 psql`?

Comment: In my experience, `psql` attempts to use a local unix socket to connect unless you explicitly specify a host. This might not work with docker. I prefer using connection urls: `psql postgres://docker:password@localhost:5432/react_query_demo_db`

Comment: @Bergi - both are giving me 'role' errors -------- 1. `docker exec reactquery_demo-db-1 psql` -> psql: error: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist -------- 2. `psql postgres://docker:password@localhost:5432/reactquery_demo-db-1` -> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "docker" does not exist

Comment: also just to check. I am assuming that I should be trying to connect to the actual container NOT the db. EX: using the appended `-1` shows in the running docker gui? I have tried both in your suggested commands.

Comment: Sorry, those would need to be `docker exec react_query_demo_db-1 psql -d reactquery_demo_db -U docker` (instead of using the login name `root` for the db username)  and `psql postgres://docker:password@localhost:5432/reactquery_demo_db` (corrected database name, I mispasted the container name).

Comment: Are you certain that the role really exists? You didn't change the *docker-compose* config after first creating the services? Afaik the `POSTGRES_USER` is only evaluated on first startup, when the database doesn't exist and is initialised. So if you put that in there later, the database was created with the standard `postgres` user as root. Maybe try that?